# Need Worksheet_Change macro to work for all sheets in workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel workbook that has 2 worksheets, Outstanding and Complete.  When on the Outstanding worksheet, I want the WorkSheet_Change function to move the current row to the Complete worksheet when column Z is changed to Complete. And, when on the Complete worksheet, I want the WorkSheet_Change function to move the current row to the Outstanding worksheet when column Z is changed to Outstanding.  I can do this for one worksheet if I put the macro under that worksheet in VBA but I cannot get it to work when it is under a Module for the workbook.  Since I cannot use the WorkSheet_Change in multiple macros in one workbook (ie, cannot just create the same macro under each sheet) I must figure out how to make it work under a Module.  This is the code that works when it is under one worksheet, but it only works for that worksheet.  How can I get it to work for both worksheets when it is in a Module for the workbook?

```
'Remove Case Sensitivity
  Option Compare Text
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   ' On Error Resume Next - I took this out of this code that I found on the internet because it apparently causes problems
    
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
        'If Cell that is edited is in column Z and the value is Complete then
    If Target.Column = 26 And Target.Cells(1).Value = "Complete" Then
        'Define last row on Complete worksheet to know where to place the row of data
        LrowCompleted = Sheets("Complete").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        'Copy and paste data
        Range("A" & Target.Row & ":Z" & Target.Row).Copy Sheets("Complete").Range("A" & LrowCompleted + 1)
        'Delete Row from the ActiveSheet
        Range("A" & Target.Row & ":Z" & Target.Row).Delete xlShiftUp
     ElseIf Target.Column = 26 And Target.Cells(1).Value = "Outstanding" Then
        'Define last row on Outstanding worksheet to know where to place the row of data
        LrowCompleted = Sheets("Outstanding").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        'Copy and paste data
        Range("A" & Target.Row & ":Z" & Target.Row).Copy Sheets("Outstanding").Range("A" & LrowCompleted + 1)
        'Delete Row from the ActiveSheet
        Range("A" & Target.Row & ":Z" & Target.Row).Delete xlShiftUp

   End If
     
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you not just check the name of the worksheet to which the target belongs to determine which actions to take.  Target.name?

Comment: In the workbook code module you can use `Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)`  Check `Sh.Name` to see which sheet is being changed, and take the appropriate action.

Comment: I'm sure that would work too but I know very little about coding and since both of the solutions that were provided work, I will just use one of them.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done this test.

1. In a general module Module1, we create a subroutine `DoWorksheet_Change()`, using `ActiveSheet` to identify the Worksheet that we are editing.

```
'Remove Case Sensitivity
Option Compare Text
Option Explicit

Sub DoWorksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    ' On Error Resume Next - I took this out of this code that I found on the internet because it apparently causes problems
      
    Dim LrowCompleted As Long
      
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    'Debug.Print ActiveSheet.Name
    'If Cell that is edited is in column Z and the value is Complete then
    If Target.Column = 26 And Target.Cells(1).Value = "Complete" Then
        'Define last row on Complete worksheet to know where to place the row of data
        LrowCompleted = Sheets("Complete").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        'Copy and paste data
        ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Target.Row & ":Z" & Target.Row).Copy Sheets("Complete").Range("A" & LrowCompleted + 1)
        'Delete Row from the ActiveSheet
        ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Target.Row & ":Z" & Target.Row).Delete xlShiftUp
    ElseIf Target.Column = 26 And Target.Cells(1).Value = "Outstanding" Then
        'Define last row on Outstanding worksheet to know where to place the row of data
        LrowCompleted = Sheets("Outstanding").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        'Copy and paste data
        ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Target.Row & ":Z" & Target.Row).Copy Sheets("Outstanding").Range("A" & LrowCompleted + 1)
        'Delete Row from the ActiveSheet
        ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Target.Row & ":Z" & Target.Row).Delete xlShiftUp

    End If
     
    'Debug.Print ActiveSheet.Name
    
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

2. In both Outstanding and Complete sheets private module, we put the same code, calling the public macro `DoWorksheet_Change()`.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  DoWorksheet_Change Target
End Sub
```

Comment: You have Target, so it’s safer to use `Target.Parent` and not `ActiveSheet`

Comment: I changed ActiveSheet to Target.Parent and it works so I will keep it like that.  I'm not sure why it is safer, but I trust those that know more than I do.

Comment: Thanks jacouh.  This worked perfectly.  There is no way I could have done it myself.  I ended up adding another worksheet and was able to just add another Elseif for it.

Answer (score 2):

### A Workbook Sheet Change: Copy Rows

- Copy the following code into the `ThisWorkbook` module.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Dim Success As Boolean
    On Error GoTo ClearError

    Const CRITERIA_COLUMN As Long = 26
    
    Dim wsNames(): wsNames = VBA.Array("Complete", "Outstanding")
    Dim FirstRows(): FirstRows = VBA.Array("A2:Z2", "A2:Z2")
    Dim Criteria(): Criteria = VBA.Array("Outstanding", "Complete")
    
    Dim aIndex: aIndex = Application.Match(Sh.Name, wsNames, 0)
    If IsError(aIndex) Then Exit Sub
    
    aIndex = aIndex - 1
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = Me.Sheets(wsNames(aIndex))
    
    Dim srg As Range
    With sws.Range(FirstRows(aIndex))
        Set srg = .Resize(sws.Rows.Count - .Row + 1)
    End With
    
    Dim irg As Range: Set irg = Intersect(srg.Columns(CRITERIA_COLUMN), Target)
    If irg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim urg As Range, cel As Range
    
    For Each cel In irg.Cells
        If StrComp(CStr(cel.Value), Criteria(aIndex), vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            If urg Is Nothing Then Set urg = cel Else Set urg = Union(urg, cel)
        End If
    Next cel
    
    If urg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    aIndex = (aIndex + 1) Mod 2
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = Me.Sheets(wsNames(aIndex))
    If dws.FilterMode Then dws.ShowAllData
    
    Dim dfCell As Range
    
    With dws.Range(FirstRows(aIndex))
        Dim dlCell As Range: Set dlCell = .Resize(dws.Rows.Count - .Row + 1) _
            .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
        If dlCell Is Nothing Then
            Set dfCell = .Cells(1)
        Else
            Set dfCell = .Cells(1).Offset(dlCell.Row - .Row + 1)
        End If
    End With
     
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    With Intersect(srg, urg.EntireRow)
        .Copy dfCell
        .Delete xlShiftUp
    End With
    
    Success = True
    
ProcExit:
    If Not Application.EnableEvents Then Application.EnableEvents = True
    If Not Success Then MsgBox "Something went wrong.", vbCritical
    Exit Sub
ClearError:
    Debug.Print "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
End Sub
```

Comment: Wow!  I can't believe how quickly you all answered.  And both work great but I am going to use the second one from jacouh because I just found out that there will be another sheet and when I tried to add it to this code in the VBA.Array, it would not work.  I am sure I am not doing it the right way though. This is what I did:

Dim wsNames(): wsNames = VBA.Array("Complete", "Outstanding", "Pending")
Dim FirstRows(): FirstRows = VBA.Array("A2:Z2", "A2:Z2")
Dim Criteria(): Criteria = VBA.Array("Outstanding", "Complete", "Pending")